# Sending data to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If there is a sheet 1 that gets data from an online form and it needs to auto populate sheet 2, what is the formula to send data from 1A:1G of sheet 1 to  1A:1G of sheet 2 if 1H on sheet 1 is occupied.

Comment: Your question is too broad, please add more information and new tags, how are you suppose to get this data from a form and parse it into Excel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=IF(Sheet1!$H$1<>"",Sheet1!A1,"")
```

and copy across.